# How can I from the client use the Firebase Admin SDK priviliged functions using Socket.io?

Tags: sockets, express, firebase, vue.js, firebase-admin

You see, lets say I have a server with express with only one route ("/") it is a single page application powered by Vuejs where users can login and register, for simplicity the user UI is not the same as the admin UI but they both lived in the same application.

Now, since the Firebase **Admin SDK** can perform **various operations without the need of any authentication process**:

1.- Can I from the client be an **Admin** with these **privileged operations** and at the same time show a completely different UI than the users through Vuejs?

2.- How can I using **Socket.io** enabled this operations between my server and my admin client if is possible?

3.- If somehow It is possible, It is safe to use Socket.io than a regular API calls?

Comment: You appear to be posting a lot of very open-ended questions here to Stack Overflow.  This isn't really the best place for questions that are looking for conversation.  Instead, consider starting a conversation on firebase-talk.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk

Comment: I did It and this was my response: Unfortunately, your recent post to the Firebase Google Group group was denied by a group moderator.